# What are the pros & cons of 2 types of spring testing

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, microservices, spring-test

In my current project we are working on microservices(web app).
In unit tests we try to cover 85-90% of our code. I have noticed 2 approaches of testing using spring:

- Inject a controller and invoke its methods directly
- Form a proper request where you can specify cookies, headers... and then make a call

Moreover, we won't be able to test authentication with the 1 approach.

Which of the next spring testing ways should be used? And what are the (dis-)advantages of each type?

```
@RestController
class MyController {
    @PostMapping(path="/path")
    public String handle(@RequestBody MyRequest request) {
        //service invoked
        return "some value";
    }
}
```

**JUnit approach #1**

```
@LotsOfAnnotations
class ControllerTest1 {
    @Autowired
    private MyController myController;
    @Test
    public String verboseNameTest() {
        // Mock 3rd party calls
        ....
        // Form request
        MyRequest request = new MyRequest();
        // Invoke testing method
        myController.handle(request);
        // Assert
    }
}
```

**JUnit approach #2**

```
@LotsOfAnnotations
class ControllerTest2 {
    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate testTemplate;
    private MockRestServiceServer server;
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webAppContext;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        server = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(testTemplate.getRestTemplate());
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.webAppContext).build();
    }
    @Test
    public String verboseNameTest() {
        // Mock 3rd party calls
        ....
        // Form request
        String jsonStringRequest = "{}";
        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders
                    .post("/path")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(jsonStringRequest);
        // Make a call
        MvcResult result = this.mockMvc
                    .perform(requestBuilder)
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andReturn();
        // Assert
    }
}
```

Comment: For my projects, we use approach 1 on service layer while approach two on controller test.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you need to understand when to mock the service and when to make a direct call.

In your first approach you are directly calling the web service so let's say for example you have a huge code base and multiple developers are working at a time so you would get constant updates in the classes and if you want to test your piece of code(which is why you use JUnit) then you making direct call can result in error/ failed test case because someone might have changed something.

In second approach or mocking basically removes that possibility by mocking the other service which your code would be needing so that will make you code test easier.

But there are people who questions what's the use of mocking when you are not even testing the whole thing which is true up to certain point but the main reason for mocking is to test your piece of code only irrespective of other services that code is dependent on. Also if you talk about making actual service call that should be part of integration testing or end to end testing.

Comment: Both approaches mock dependencies in the same way. By mocking i mean mocking another HTTP calls. Someone may constantly keep changing the code. Both ways will not break until response changed. Additionally, in our team everyone except me is using the 1 approach. And yes, we change functionality  every day, but we do not break the response. Our different tests pass, but i was asking what are the advised practices. And what will i face in the future with each way?